# How to add item to arrayproperty in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Trying to push an item in my itemsarray property for my redux reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    cartOpen: false,
    total: 0
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':

            var newstate = Object.assign({}, state,
                {items: [state.items, ...action.payload.found]}
            );

            console.log('testing=newstate', newstate);

            var newTotal = 0;
            console.log('testing newstate', newstate)

            newstate.items.forEach(it => {
                newTotal += it.price;
                console.log('testing price', it.price)
            });
            newstate.total = newTotal;
            newstate.cartOpen = true
            //debugger;
            return newstate;


        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default Cart;
```

The action.payload.found looks like this:

```
{
  "id":"100",
  "price":10
}
```

How can I push this object to the items array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using spread operator on wrong item. You should use this instead:

```
        var newstate = Object.assign({}, state,
            {items: [...state.items, action.payload.found]}
        );
```

Your code `{items: [state.items, ...action.payload.found]}` actually tried to spread `action.payload.found` which is an object and then returned an array where the first item was the old array followed by the values from `action.payload.found`

For instance assume original `state.items` was `[A, B, C]` and `action.payload.found` was `{id: "100", price: 10}`, then `{items: [state.items, ...action.payload.found]}` would actually return `[[A, B, C], "100", 10]`. However you want it to return `[A, B, C, {id: "100", price: 10}]` instead. Therefore you need to spread `state.items`.